# Is there a way to make some sort of UI in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, user-interface

Title says it all. Is there a package or something that lets there be a frontend?

Comment: You can use [Electron](https://electronjs.org).

Comment: Im order to answer this question you need to know that NoseJS is a **Technology** that lets you run JS in server side and that JS is a **Programming Language**. Now in order to create a UI you need to pass some JS and or HTML to a client side engin to present your results to the user. You can do this with opening a local host website or use Electron to create apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node and express to server static/dynamic html.

Check [this](https://medium.com/@waelyasmina/a-guide-into-using-handlebars-with-your-express-js-application-22b944443b65) out. It is a step by step tutorial.